# Calculating the force on each of two directions needed to move object to destination

Tags: geometry, physics

Given the following:
[image: Two Forces Diagram]

How would you calculate the forces needed on the `v` and `u` directions to move point `A` to point `B`?

I know this should be simple, but the answer is escaping me.
I'm also unsure of how to tag this question, so any help in that department would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the ratio of the forces to match the ratio of the displacements.  There is nothing to set the magnitude of the force.  So $\frac {f_v}{f_u}=\frac {\Delta v}{\Delta u}=\frac 34$  You have calculated the angles correctly, but don't need them.

Comment: As suspected, way too simple :D Thanks for the help!